# How to write a simple mock of an API call that returns async

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is this sample application that has a level db Node JS library, but my server doesn't currently have level db installed and I don't need it.

How can I write a simple class that would just mock the API calls.

The store variable is the library I want to mock, and it has 2 API calls:

```
  store.put   
  store.get
```

It has 2 API calls:

```
const store = level('./data/dbname123', { valueEncoding: 'json' });

save() {
  debug(`saving id: ${this.id}`);
  const properties = attributes.reduce((props, attr) => {
    props[attr] = this[attr];
    return props;
  }, { fields: this.fields });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    store.put(this.id, properties, (error) => {
      if (error) { return reject(error); }
      resolve(this);
    });
  });
}


 static find(id) {
    debug(`fetching id: ${id}`)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      store.get(id, (error, properties) => {
        if (error) { return reject(error); }
        resolve(new Ticket(properties));
      });
    });
  }
```

How can I quickly just mock those? I'm not too familiar with this style of JavaScript but it because of the promise wrapper I'm not sure if that is async call or?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "mock" in this case, but `var stock = { put: function () {}, get: function() {} };` would seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create an object with `put` and `get` methods on it that simulate what those methods do. Just make sure your functions follow the expected conventions — for example calling the callback with an error as the first argument if there's a problem.

Obviously this can be more involved and there are tools like [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org) that can help if you have to mock existing functions.

For example:

```js
// simple mocks for store.get and store.put
let store = {
    put(id, properties, fn){
        // add whatever behavior you need and call callback fn
        fn(null) // calling with null indicates no error. 
    },
    get(id, fn){
        // make some properties
        let props = {
            someProperties: "Hello",
            id: id
        }
        // call callback
        fn(null, props)
    }
}


function save() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      store.put('id', 'properties', (error) => {
        if (error) { return reject(error); }
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
  
function find(id) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        store.get(id, (error, properties) => {
          if (error) { return reject(error); }
          resolve(properties);
        });
      });
    }

// try them out

find("21")
.then(console.log)

save()
.then(() => console.log("done"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer doesn't correspond to your question but to mock your library you can create your own storage

```
const store = function () {
  var data = {};

  return {
    put: function(id, props, fn) {
       data[id] = props;
       fn(null);
    },
    get: function(id, fn) {
      fn(null, data[id]);
    } 
  }
}();
```

If you define your storage like it, you mock your library